# calling a secure service using a service reference

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

There is an external secure service that I am consuming in my .net class by making a web reference to it and passing it the username token like so:

```
MyWebService objWS = new MyWebService();
UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken("User","Password", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
objWS.RequestSoapContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60;
objWS.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
objWS.RequestSoapContext.Security.MustUnderstand = false;
```

when I make service reference to the same service url and try to pass in the username and password using ClientCredentials it fails.

I have no idea about the external service. Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks for your time...

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: that toolbar doesnt load sometimes when I use firefox.. I dunno why

Comment: This is not a question about WCF but about WSE.

Comment: @Ladislav: what I was trying to get at is that I was able to connect to a secure service thru a wse generated proxy class, but not when I use a proxy class that gets generated when I create a service reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install WSE3 and in the proxy generated inherit from Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol instead of the default System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.

Then the service proxy object would get the Security property.

```
objWS.RequestSoapContext.Security
```

which I can then use to pass in the UsernameToken.

This is a hack and I have not found a better way to do it yet. Regenerating the proxy will always involve that extra step of having to manually edit the proxy again, as above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the service over https?  The server may require a client certificate.
I found this example usage of.  [UsernameToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819938.aspx)